# Creating multiple nodes in a linked list

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a function that saves values entered into various elements of a given linked list (plus and lens), then display the result (id). I can enter, save, and display this only one time, but as soon as I exit the function or try to enter another set of values, it only shows the most recent one. The user is prompted to select whether to write something or to exit the program, within the main.c file. I think I'm only creating one node, but not sure how to fix it. Since, the number of entries is unknown, I can't just hard code the number of sets of data I want (or nodes). My code is below:

Within header function:

```
typedef struct nodetreat{
    int id;                 
    char user[51];      
    char text[141];     
   
    struct nodetreat *next;  
}treat;
```

Within main.c:

```
int num = 0;
scanf("%d", &num);

if(num== 1) {
  treatmaker(treatList);
}
```

Within function (treatmaker):

```
treat *treatmaker(treat *treatList) {

  int i;
  int plus= 0;
  int lens = 0;
  struct nodetreat *new_node;

  new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct nodetreat));

  printf("Enter a name: ");
  fgets(new_node->user, 51, stdin);

  printf("Enter the text: ");
  fgets(new_node->text, 141, stdin);

  for(i = 0; i < strlen(new_node->user) - 1; i++) {
    plus += new_node->user[i];
  }

  lens= strlen(new_node->text) - 1;

  new_node->id = plus + lens;

  printf("id is %d.\n", new_node->id);
}
```

So my question is, what do I fix so that my linked list can hold multiple id's or nodes?

Comment: What does "plus and lens" mean?

Comment: Show the declaration of the variable "treatList".

Comment: the function: `fgets()` includes the trailing newline `\n` in the data,  You probably don't want to keep that newline.  Suggest: `new_node->user[ strcspn( new_node->user, "\n") ] = '\0';`    Then you probably will not need the `-1` on the calls to `strlen()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `new_node->next` to `nodetreat` in the function `treatmaker` and then return `new_node` in the end.

```
treat *treatmaker(treat *treatList)
{
    // do something here...
    now_node->next = treatList;
    return new_node;
}
```

In your `main.c` file, you would then have to overwrite `treatList` with the returned `new_node`.

```
treatList = treatmaker(treatlist);
```

And by the way, I would suggest allocating memory for `new_node` like this:

```
new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
```